# How to get the results from two table based on mobile number in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

Here i have two tables, i want write a select results from that two tables based on mobile number.

First Table

> new_staff

```
staff_id              firstName        Mobile          userType

  1                  Soupranjali       9986125566       Teacher
  2                  Sujata            8553880306       Teacher
```

Second Table

> new_student

```
student_id           first_Name        fatherMobile        user_type

  1                  janarthan         8553880306         Student
  2                  Santanu           8277904354         Student
```

here **8553880306**  both table available so i need output like this

> Expected Results

```
    {
  "status": "Success",
  "Profile": [
    {
      "staff_id": "2",
      "firstName": "Sujata",
      "userType" : "Teacher"
    },
    {
      "student_id": "1",
      "firstName": "janarthan",
      "user_type" : "Student"
    },
  ]
}
```

So tried like this but i unable to get the answer, so please anyone help me,

> my model

```
 public function android_memberList($mobile)
            {
                $this->db->select('new_staff.staff_id, new_staff.firstName, new_staff.userType, new_student.student_id, new_student.first_Name, new_student.user_type');
                //$this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('new_staff');
                $this->db->join('new_student', 'new_student.fatherMobile  = new_staff.Mobile');
                $query = $this->db->get();

                # result_array is used to convert the data into an array
                $result = $query->result_array(); // or  $result = $query->result_array()[0]; 
                echo json_encode($query);
            }
```

**Updated Answer**

```
     [
  {
    "staff_id": "2",
    "firstName": "Sujata",
    "userType": "Teacher",
    "student_id": "1",
    "first_Name": "janarthan",
    "user_type": "Student"
  }
]
```

> Update answer 2

```
    [
  [
    {
      "staff_id": "2",
      "firstName": "Sujata",
      "userType": "Teacher",
      "student_id": "1",
      "first_Name": "janarthan",
      "user_type": "Student"
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Print out (edit your question) what have you got instead? Is there any error message?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check datatype of mobile column on both table.

They must have same datatype to perform join operation.

Comment: Yes, both table datatype i given in bigint

Comment: Can you please check my select query in both table it is correct? in my query i not giving mobile number

Comment: Try to print your query using $this->db->last_query() after query. i am able to find records with phpmyadmin. I get this query when i print query SELECT * FROM `new_staff` as `staff` JOIN `new_student` as `student` ON `staff`.`Mobile` = `student`.`fatherMobile` . You will get results if you have correct data types.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
public function android_memberList($mobile)
{
    $this->db->select('new_staff.staff_id, new_staff.firstName, new_staff.userType, new_student.student_id, new_student.firstName, new_student.user_type');
    //$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('new_staff');
    $this->db->join('new_student', 'new_student.fatherMobile  = new_staff.Mobile');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    # result_array is used to convert the data into an array
    $result = $query->result_array(); // or  $result = $query->result_array()[0]; 
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

> When you use `result_array` it will come as ZERO indexed array. You can choose that or you can remove it as using comment on above code

Comment: Mr @ Abdulla Nilam , i tried your code, please check my updated Answer, i am getting like that answer, some unwanted value in comming how remove that

Comment: @subikshanM use this `$this->db->select('new_staff.staff_id, new_staff.firstName, new_staff.userType, new_student.student_id, new_student.firstName, new_student.user_type');`

Comment: and seems you missed this `$result = $query->result_array();` and this `echo json_encode($result);`

Comment: I changed, but still i am getting same , some unwanted values also coming

Comment: add in your answer

Comment: Mr @ Abdulla Nilam i am not getting can you please update your code

Comment: add code given in my answer. and post the output. its changed

Comment: Mr @ Abdulla Nilam, i getting all answer in same object, i don't want like this can you please see expected results, i need like that

Comment: try this `echo json_encode(array_chunk($result,3));`

Comment: I tried your code but not getting proper answer, please see Update answer 2

Comment: Mr @ Abdulla Nilam , what happened ?